# Resources not re-created with Terraform and vSphere

Tags: terraform, vsphere

I'm a noob with this combo, so I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

Terraform with the vSphere provider, and during Chef provisioning it errors out.  Then, when re-planning and re-applying, it wants to create the instance as new despite it already existing in some form:

> Terraform will perform the following actions:
>
> # vsphere_virtual_machine.prdsat02 will be created
>     + resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "prdsat02" {

It does not choose to destroy and re-create, which is where I think things go off the proverbial rails, and then of course the apply fails:

> $ terraform apply -input=false $PLAN 
>   vsphere_virtual_machine.prdsat02: Creating...
>
> Error: error cloning virtual machine: The name 'prdsat02' already exists.
>
> on vm-prdsat02.tf line 2, in resource "vsphere_virtual_machine"
>   "prdsat02":    2: resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "prdsat02"  {
>
> ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1

I'm expecting it to want to destroy and re-create, and while that's likely disabled for safety, I must be missing the bit that enables it.

You'll probably need more info than I can think to include, so please ask whatever comes to mind and I'll update.

Thanks!

- terraform v0.12.16 (the excellent harbottle RPM)
- terraform-provider-vsphere v1.12.0

Comment: What are you doing for state management?

Comment: Single user and single project; so local, at this earliest of stages.